# A question on orthocentre of a triangle.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

If origin is the orthocentre of a triangle formed by $A(\cos X,\sin X)$, $B(\cos Y, \sin Y)$, $C(\cos Z, \sin Z)$, then what is the angle $BAC$?

I tried using the formula for orthocentre which involves $\tan$ of an angle and stuff but it's becoming difficult.

Please help.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Instead of trying to solve this problem with coordinate geometry, just use regular euclidean geometry and draw a couple of pictures.

Comment: @Bob1123 is kind of more difficult then :p

Comment: Hint: the problem tells you that all $3$ vertices are at the same distance from the orthocenter.

Comment: @dxiv so does it imply that it is also a circumcentre?

Comment: @LokeshSangewar Precisely. In which case the triangle must be $\;\cdots\;$

Comment: @dxiv which then again implies that it is an equilateral triangle which again implies that answer to the question is 60 degrees?

Comment: @LokeshSangewar Correct.

Comment: Thank you for the help

Comment: See, no coordinates! Also, @dxiv, you should write up this solution so that the problem is answered.

Comment: Hehe...yeah!! I unnecessarily made it complicated

Comment: That happens a lot when using coordinate geometry, so much so that the method is often referred to as "coordinate bashing".

Comment: @Bob1123 I posted the answer as a CW to recognize the teamwork.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(*Expanded from the comments.*)  The problem implies that all $3$ vertices are at the same distance from the orthocenter, meaning that the orthocenter coincides with the circumcenter, which in turn means that the triangle must be equilateral.

Answer (score 1):

The three points are all one unit away from the origin so they are all on the circumference of the unit circle.

The origin is the orthocenter so any line through $O$ and one of the vertices is perpendicular to the line through the other two vertices (e.g. line through $OA$ is perpendicular to $BC$).

$|OB| = |OC|$ so  $OBC$ is isosceles. The altitude of the isosceles triangle $OBC$ is perpendicular to  segment $BC$ and goes through $O$. As $OA$ is another line through $O$ that is perpendicular to $BC$, this means that $OA$ produced coincides with the altitude of $OBC$ and therefore it also bisects $BC$

This means that $B$  and $C$ are symmetric in the line $OA$. 
A similar argument shows that $A$  and $C$ are symmetric in the altitude $OB$ and that $A$ and $B$ are symmetric in the altitude $OC$. So the triangle is equilateral and the required angle is $2 \pi/3$.

---

This argument tries to avoid any explicit facts about the circumcenter.

Answer (score 1):

It is a classical theorem that the reflection $H'$ of the orthocenter $H=O$ with respect to any side belongs to the circumscribed circle (http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/AltitudeAndCircumcircle.shtml#Explanation). Then, $HH'$ is the perpendicular bissector of the corresponding side, say $AB$. Thus the angle $AOH'$ is $\pi/3$, thus angle $AOB$ is $2 \pi/3$. Doing the same for the other angles, we end up with triangle $ABC$ equilateral.